# Angular 2 (keydown.enter) can not preventDefault()

Tags: angular

the `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work when I use `(keydown.enter)` in template. 
This is demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/GZrVt7l6BEO2uHfWFoTQ?p=preview
Please help me.

Comment: It would be perfect if you could use stackblitz.com for demo

Comment: I don't get it. What is happening with the textarea when pressing enter what you want to prevent?

Comment: @M98 this is stackblitz.com for demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jr4gfw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @D.Simon I want the text will be display is the value that I enter in textarea not is "123"

Comment: have you tried using `event.stopPropagation()` instead?

Comment: Just leave the line `this.text="123";` and it works
https://plnkr.co/edit/KTk511NrRzTukDzWFddJ?p=preview

Comment: thanks @QuietOran, It work for me

Comment: thanks @D.Simon, but my issue is the preventDefault() doesn't work. That demo just show my issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So just to leave a proper answer here, the correct action to use in this case is `event.stopPropagation()` rather than `event.preventDefault()`.

[event.preventDefault() JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/QuietOran/uy6p6n8f/)

[event.stopPropagation() JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/QuietOran/ke9a3uvx/)

Both examples contain a small explanation for whats happening with both.