# Prevent press enter from creating new line in Angular4

Tags: html, angular, forms, input

I have a textarea that I submit while pressing Enter

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvxifq-uyxteg

```
<textarea class="message-area" (keyup.enter)="ValidateCommentAndPost(commentErr, $event);" [(ngModel)]="comment" matInput #commentErr="ngModel"></textarea>
```

I would like to disable the new Line while I press enter, so I took some information on the web and did .

```
ValidateCommentAndPost(ngComment:NgModel, event?:KeyboardEvent){
    event.preventDefault();
    if((ngComment.invalid && (ngComment.dirty || ngComment.touched)) && ngComment.errors) {
        this.ResetComment();
    } else {
        this.PostComment();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, also, `return false;` still create a white line.

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 (keydown.enter) can not preventDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276135/angular-2-keydown-enter-can-not-preventdefault)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add event to capture enter and prevent the default behaviour. 
Add the keydown event to your component html

```
<textarea required
(keydown.enter)="onKeydown($event)" (keyup.enter)="ValidateCommentAndPost(commentErr, $event);" pattern="/^[/\S/]+$/i" [(ngModel)]="value" matInput #commentErr="ngModel"></textarea>
```

and add this to your component ts file

```
onKeydown(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: this one was very stupid ahah, Thank you. I completely forgot the new line is apply on key down... thanks

Comment: I echo the keydown observation. I was using keyup to no avail